# Unknown column in Having Clause

Tags: mysql-5.7

Getting this apparently nonsensical error

```
Error code: 1054 Unknown column in having Clause
```

while running this query

```
Select date(START_TS), resource_key, count(INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID) 
From tableName
Group By date(START_TS), resource_key 
Having date(START_TS) > '2020-08-27' and resource_key in(772122, 772134);
```

Although the objective has been achieved by using Where Clause before Group By, but this error is still bothering. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havin can only use colmuns that are in the GROUP By or SELECT. But START_TS as columns doesn't exist, so you must use an ALIAS  to get your dates.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
  `START_TS` date,
  `resource_key` int,
  `INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID` varchar(4)
);

INSERT INTO tableName
  (`START_TS`, `resource_key`, `INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID`)
VALUES
  ('2020-08-27' , 772122, 'test'),
    ('2020-08-27' , 772122, 'test')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
Select date(START_TS) date_ts, MIN(resource_key), count(INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID) 
From tableName
Group By date(START_TS), resource_key 
Having date_ts >= '2020-08-27' and resource_key in (772122, 772134);

| date_ts    | MIN(resource_key) | count(INTERACTION_RESOURCE_ID) |
| ---------- | ----------------- | ------------------------------ |
| 2020-08-27 | 772122            | 2                              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/22)